# highlight cell if isblank vba

Tags: vba, excel, conditional-formatting

Hi i have the following code but it prommpts an error range of object_worksheet failed. I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong (i've found the vba code using `record` macro and simply copy and pasted except i've replaced all of `selection` to `ws.range(emptyrow)` to indicate the range is up to the last cell with values. Also, if i were to change the sub to `sub highlightemptycell_change()` and have `if` statement as such: "if any cells are changed then do the following" how would i write that in a vba language?

```
sub highlightemptycell()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim r As Range
    Dim emptyrow As Long
    Dim err As Range

    Set ws = Worksheets("Master")
    emptyrow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1    '<<< safer....

    ws.Range(emptyrow).FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
    ws.Range(emptyrow).FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
        "=ISBLANK(ws.range(emptyrow)"
    ws.Range(emptyrow).FormatConditions(ws.Range(emptyrow).FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With ws.Range(emptyrow).FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 5287936
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
```

Comment: You can't just pass a number to Range()...

Comment: change `ws.Range(emptyrow)` to `ws.Range("A" & emptyrow)` or `ws.Cells(emptyrow,"A")`

Comment: In addition to what others have written, "=ISBLANK(ws.range(emptyrow)" you are missing a parenthesis in the formula.

Comment: i get a subscript out of range for `ws.range("A" & emptyrow).Formatconditions(1).` and an error end of the statement for `"=Isblank"`

Comment: @Doolie1106 Probably there are no format conditions in ws.range("A" & emptyrow)

Comment: @Doolie1106 With regard to the error in the formula, post exactly what formula you are using.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you are doing.  In particular, I'm not sure of the significance of this line,

```
ws.Range(emptyrow).FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
```

especially when there are no conditional formats in the cell at the time it is executed.

But the following macro seems to do what yours would do if it were cleaned up a bit and written with proper syntax

```
Option Explicit
Sub highlightemptycell()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim r As Range
    Dim emptyrow As Long
    Dim err As Range

    Dim rEmptyRow As Range '<-- range object added to use below

    Set ws = Worksheets("Master")
    Set rEmptyRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(rowoffset:=1)    '<<< safer....

With rEmptyRow.FormatConditions
    If .Count > 0 Then .Item(1).StopIfTrue = False
    .Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
        "=ISBLANK(" & rEmptyRow.Address & ")"
        .Item(.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With .Item(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 5287936
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
End With
End Sub
```